# add style on static block

Tags: magento2, static-block, magento2.3.0

I have HTML code for slideshows and [CSS and javascript] but on the static block in magneto 2.3 I can not add a link to CSS and javascript Example

.

before  save

```
<script src = "http://localhost:8080/style_slideshow/1.css" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But after save

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

---

on magneto 1.9 it working

Answer (score 0):

you have to disable the WYSIWYG 
follow these path stroes > setting > configuration > general >content management > WYSIWYG Options

set to disable by default